# Entity Framework: Import tree of entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a scenario where I want to serialize a tree of entities to an XML file and then restore that tree of entities to another database using Entity Framework.  I am curious as to how I should go about adding the child entities?  Should I simply deserialize the tree and then call `context.AddToXXX(xxx)` on the parent node?  Would that import all of the children, too?

EDIT: What would happen to the current data if the tree already existing but the serialized data was different?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Context.DbSet.Add` method it will mark all of the entities in the object graph as new and try to insert them when you `SaveChanges`.

If you use the `Context.DbSet.Attach` method, the context will start tracking all of the entities but it will mark them all as unmodified and won't do anything with them when you `SaveChanges`.

In either case you can use `Context.Entry().State` to explicitly set the state of entities before calling `SaveChanges`.